# Where to store resource files with Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, directory-structure, resource-files

I've got a JSON file containing a list of time zones which I want to reference in my project, but I'm not sure of where I should store this.

I'm considering making a directory called /resources or /assets

Alternatively, I could store in /src/services, as this is kind of the data layer of my app. The one problem with this though is that this file is a JSON file and not actually a service...

Any opinions on where to store this kind of thing?

Answer (score 3):

John Papa's guide is the best when it comes to code structuring: Please refer to this url: https://johnpapa.net/angular-app-structuring-guidelines/

It talks about where you should put certain files and components in your Angular project.

Comment: He doesn't address the question of static assets per se. Still, that's quite a nice resource...

Comment: He addresses static content starting on the line: "All content assets go in another root folder. Your naming may vary."